# Can't prevent page from refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, html

I got some very helpful suggestions from a post a couple days ago (thank you to all who responded) and a new issue has come up that I can't seem to solve.

I have a php file that is a registration form posting data to a MySQL database.  The form posts correctly, and after posting, the html updates via a JS function.  But the update doesn't stay on the page long enough to be read and the page refreshes.

Here is the code, and below that a list of all the things I have tried to fix the problem without any success:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){


$dbServername = "mysite.com";
$dbUsername = "myusername";
$dbPassword = "12345";
$dbName = "dbname";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

$firstname   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastname']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO registration (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
mysqli_close($conn);

unset($_POST);

header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}


?>


<html lang="en">
  
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/styles.css" />
    <!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="content"
    />

    <title>Site | Page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <span
              ><a href="index.html" class="logo"
                >Company </a
              ></span
            >
            <span class="logo2"
              >Text</span
            >
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 menu-padding">
            <span class="menu menu-span"
              ><a href="index.html" class="menu-link">Home</a>
            </span>
            <span class="menu menu-span">
              <a href="about.html" class="menu-link">About</a>
            </span>
            <span class="menu menu-span"
              ><a href="search.html" class="menu-link active">Search</a></span
            >
            <span class="menu menu-span"
              ><a href="contact.html" class="menu-link">Contact</a></span
            >

            <span class="menu menu-span language">
              <a href="../spanish/inicio-esp.html" class="menu-link">Español</a>
            </span>
            <span class="menu menu-span language"
              ><a href="../portuguese/inicio-port.html" class="menu-link"
                >Português</a
              ></span
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="registrationOne">
    <div class="container">


<form name="regForm" method="post" action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> onsubmit="thankReg();">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="">First Name:</label>
              <input name="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="">Last Name:</label>
              <input name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>

</div>
<button
            name="submitButton"
            type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            id="registrationTwo"
            
            >
            Register
          </button>

</form>
        
    </div>
    </div>
  
  </body>
  <script src="script/index.js"></script>
  
  </html>
```

And then the JS:

```
function validateRegForm(event) {
  let valid = true;
  let first = document.forms["regForm"]["firstname"].value;
  let last = document.forms["regForm"]["lastname"].value;

  if (first.length < 2) {
    alert("Please enter a first name at least of at least two characters");
    valid = false;
  } else if (last.length < 2) {
    alert("Please enter a last name at least of at least two characters");
    valid = false;
  } else {
    document.forms["regForm"].submit();
  }
  if (!valid) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

let regClick = document.getElementById("registrationTwo");
regClick.addEventListener("click", validateRegForm);

function thankReg() {
  let regOneElement = document.getElementById("registrationOne");
  regOneElement.innerHTML = `<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h2 class="thankYouReg">Thank you for registering with Pro.Social.<br /><br />Please check your email for your unique search link to get started. <br /><br />If you do not receive an email from us in the next few minutes, please contact us via the Contact page.</h2>
</div>
</div>`;
}
```

Here are all the things I have tried but none has worked:

- Adding return false; to end of thankReg()
- Adding onsubmit="return thankReg();" to form instead of just onsubmit="thankReg();"
- Adding return false; to thankReg() and onsubmit="return thankReg(); to form
- Adding event.preventDefault() to end of thankReg()
- Nesting thankReg() in validateRegForm() and calling return thankReg()
- Nesting thankReg() in validateRegForm() and calling thankReg()
- Adding a second event listener that calls thankReg()
- Adding location.href = "https://www.anewpage.com"; to end of validateRegForm()
- Adding window.location.replace("http://www.anewpage.com"); to end of validateRegForm()
- Adding if (valid) {window.location.replace("https://www.prosocial.online/about.html");} to end of validateRegForm()

Any suggestions are appreciated!  Thanks again.

Comment: Are you performing a standard form POST, or are you posting the data via AJAX?  The code shown implies the former.  And if that's the case, it's not clear what your goal is here.  Posting a form is a page-level HTTP request.  It loads a new page, by definition.  If you don't want the user to leave the current page then you'll want to use AJAX.

Comment: Related question: [How to send data to 'post.php' using AJAX? (without Jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690977/how-to-send-data-to-post-php-using-ajax-without-jquery)

Comment: I'm not posting via AJAX, but I've seen a lot of answers to other similar questions recommending it, so I guess I'll have to try it.  I'm new to php so I've never used AJAX before.

Comment: AJAX has nothing to do with PHP, it's a client-side JavaScript tool. It's just a way of making a HTTP request from the browser to the server asynchronously, without needing to refresh the whole page (which is the default, historical way browsers behave). It can send a request to any server or URL, not just one which runs PHP. But anyway, if you do that, basically instead of getting PHP to output the message, you'd basically send the AJAX request, wait for the response and then, when the response is received your code runs a JS function, within which you can add your code to show the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `thankReg()` JavaScript function runs during the HTML form's `onsubmit` event. That means it runs in the browser *before* the form has been submitted to the server. A moment later of course, the form is submitted which causes a HTTP request to the server, so the browser clears the current page in anticipation of a new response to that request coming back from the server.

To allow the message to persist longer, you need to make PHP trigger the message to be displayed *after* the form has been submitted, so that it doesn't a) appear prematurely before the form has actually succeeded, and b) get immediately removed.

Since you're issuing a redirect header, this task needs to happen when the redirected page is loaded, not in the immediate response to the form submission (which the browser will never display). So adding a query parameter into that redirect URL is a good way to do it - that can be used to indicate that the thankyou message needs to be shown.

Remove the `thankReg()` function and the `onsubmit` handler which triggers it. Then, try something like this:

Amend

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

to

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?msg=thanks");
```

Then, further down the page:

```
<div id="registrationOne">
<?php
if (isset($_GET["msg"]) && $_GET["msg"] == "thanks") {
?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2 class="thankYouReg">Thank you for registering with Pro.Social.<br /><br />Please check your email for your unique search link to get started. <br /><br />If you do not receive an email from us in the next few minutes, please contact us via the Contact page.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation @ADyson!  I removed the thankReg() function and the onsubmit handler, then I put your php code snippet right below  ```<div id="registrationOne">``` and left the rest of the html as is.  But now I'm just getting a 404 error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, 404 means the URL is "Not Found" so I'd guess it probably means I made a mistake in the Location header so it's redirecting to the wrong place. What is the full URL it is showing in your browser when you get the 404?

Comment: The actual page of the form is https://www.prosocial.online/search.php and the 404 shows up as https://www.prosocial.online/search.php# (the same page but with a pound sign at the end).

Comment: For me it adds a double-quote (`"'`) not a `#`. But looking at what happens via the browser's Network tool it's the POST request when the form submits which is wrong, not the redirect. So I don't think it's related to my changes. The HTML of your `<form` tag has `action="/search.php&quot;"` - &quot is the HTML-encoded version of `"`. So I think you've accidentally typed two `"`s instead of one at the end of the `action=` attribute. It's not present in the code in your question, so I'd guess you introduced it later.

Comment: Please learn to use the debugging tools in your browser's Developer Tools (primarily the element inspector, console and network tools) to look at what your application is doing, then you can investigate these kinds of problems yourself more easily instead of just looking at the symptoms. Equally, there are many tools and techniques you can use to debug the PHP side of things too. Learning to debug is just as important a skill as learning to code in the first place, and you should be learning / being taught these techniques in parallel to the actual programming knowledge.

Comment: Yep, I had a stray quotation mark in there from when I took out the onsubmit handler.  Sorry about that.  Now it's working.  Thanks so much!  I will look into how the use the debugging tools for future issues.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can't both handle the form with php and js at the same time.

You need a page reload to handle it with PHP, while javascript is gonna lose all infos if you do so.

what you can do is use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to send the data to your back end, and update the page when you get the response

Comment: Not necessarily. `form` does have a `target` attribute.